# Подскажите, что не так? Бот присылает не ту цену

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Когда цена опускается ниже той, которую я задал, бот присылает сообщение, где цена указана та, которая была минимальной до появления той, которая мне нужна. По факту он срабатывает верно, но в сообщении answer check_price цена не та.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import telebot


def check_price():
    url = requests.get("https://funpay.com/chips/30/")
    page = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
    a = page.find_all("a", class_="tc-item")
    prices = []
    for seller in a:
        if "Вашингтон" in seller.find("div", class_="tc-server hidden-xxs").text:
            price = float(seller.find("div", class_="tc-price").find("div").text.replace(" ₽", ""))
            prices.append(price)
    return min(prices)


answer = f"цена ниже {check_price()} рублей за 1кк серебра.\n https://funpay.com/chips/30/" # вот это сообщение присылается, но там цена, которая была минимальной до появления той, которая нужна мне, то есть ниже 40


bot = telebot.TeleBot("123")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def main(message):
    bad_price = True
    while bad_price:
        time.sleep(30)
        if check_price() < 40.00:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, answer)
            bad_price = False


bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вы создаёте переменную `answer` в момент запуска бота и больше никогда не меняете её, с тех пор старое значение так и остаётся навсегда

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, конкретный пример ответа системы в answer_check_price и что вы ожидали.

Comment: Спасибо, элементарная вещь, как не понял сам))